# Anonymous count with nhibernate criteria?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, detachedcriteria, nhibernate-criteria

Is it possible to create a anoynmous count with nhibernate?

The below query throws the exception "No column *".
I could of course add a column name, but I'd prefer not to, because if I do, I'll have to lookup column names for 95 tables...

```
NHibernate.Criterion.DetachedCriteria dcIsUniqueDomainname = NHibernate.Criterion.DetachedCriteria.For<nhDBapi.Tables.clsDomains>()
               .SetProjection(
                   NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Count("*")
               )
               .Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Property.ForName("DomainID").Eq(strDomainID))
               .Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Property.ForName("DomainName").Eq(strDomainName)
           );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are Looking for `Projections.RowCount()`.

Comment: Why does the type for NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.RowCount() need to be an int32? It fails when i use long (int64)... I mean there clearly can be more than 2^32 rows, can't there ? And it's kinda ironic when it returns a negative number because of overflow or whatever...

Comment: +1, and RowCount silently is int32... I wonder why it can't convert from int32 to long, the only problem should be vice-versa...

Comment: You *can* convert the result of a RowCount projection to long by using Convert.ToInt64; it just doesn't make much sense.